# Is it possible to add a row of Input controls to Ant table for searching purposes. Please refer the Image attached

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to add a row of inputs(text inputs,dropdowns) for filtering purposes right below the column header row in a antd table.Please refer the attached image.Is it possible to do ?

[image]

Comment: It depends no how your code is made and what you want in your filter input. Can you provide a stackblitz please ?

Comment: this is just a wire frame, If you want to refer antd table implementation please do refer this link https://codesandbox.io/s/nfbl0?file=/index.js:375-392

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you treat your data, but if you just need an input, i found two possibilities :

- You can pass JSX to the `title` properties of you header array:

```
{
  title: <div>Notes<br /><input type='text' /></div>,
  dataIndex: 'note',
  width: 100,
},
```

Here i pass an input, but you can make a custom component that accept your slice of data you want to filter.

- You can add a row where every colum contains the input (custom component which will treat data passed as props):

```
{
  key:0,
  date: <input type='text' />,
  amount: <input type='text' />,
  type: <input type='text' />,
  note: <input type='text' />,
},
```

I think the second is easier to setup. Assuming you data come from a API call, they are available outside of your `data` array that you use to display datas in the table. So you can filter it to just pass whatever you want as a prop and manage it in your cutom input/select component.

It sound like duplicating data but I can't think of another way to do it.